# Finding the inverse Laplace transform of F(s)=exp(-as) as f(t)=delta(t-a) using Bromwich integral

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, laplace-transform

This is mostly a procedural question regarding how to evaluate a Bromwich integral in a case that should be simple.

I'm looking at determining the inverse Laplace transform of a simple exponential $F(s)=\exp(-as)$, $a>0$. It is known that in this case $f(t) = \delta(t-a)$. Using the Bromwich formula, with $s = x+iw$:

$$
2\pi f(t) = \int_{-\infty} ^\infty F(x+iw)\exp (xt) \exp (iwt)dw
$$

For this specific $F(s)$:

$$
2\pi f(t) = \int_{-\infty} ^\infty exp((t-a)x)exp(iw(t-a))dw
$$

$$
2\pi f(t) = \exp((t-a)x) \int_{-\infty} ^\infty \exp(iw(t-a))dw
$$

At $t = a$, this becomes:

$$
2\pi f(a) = \int_{-\infty} ^\infty dw
$$

Thus $$ f(a) -> \infty $$

This is so far consistent with a $\delta (t-a)$ function.

For all $t \neq a$:

$$
\pi f(t) = lim_{T->\infty} \exp((t-a)x) \sin(T(t-a))/(t-a)
$$

which clearly does not converge rather than being zero as expected for $f(t) = \delta (t-a)$.

Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I doubt anybody can read this, please take the time to improve the readability otherwise your question will get no attention if not closed soon.

Comment: Zaid, edited accordingly.

Comment: You can also use the slash '\' to create better looking syntax. For example $sin(x)$ becomes $\sin(x)$ and $lim$ becomes $\lim$ .

Comment: Another user made some very useful comments on this at https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/inverse-laplace-transform-of-f-s-exp-as-as-delta-t-a.904385/